# How to fix "Errors during import of audio clip..." error in Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio

I'm trying to import an MP3 file in Unity. But it won't work. It would show up as an unidentified file.

It was originally a wave file, but it wouldn't import, so I converted to MP3. Still not decoding.

I want Unity to properly decode the audio like it should and not come as an obsolete file.

[image]

Comment: Is that converted .mp3 file playing fine in windows media player or other mp3 players?

Comment: can you give us a bit more information? Import settings of that file, does it have correct fileendings on your disk? Can you replay it in another programm?